# GCC hidden optimizations

Tags: gcc, optimization

The GCC [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) lists all optimization flags being applied for the different levels of optimizations (-O1, -O2, etc.). However when compiling and measuring a benchmark program (e.g. cBench's automotive_bitcount) there is a significant difference when applying an optimization level instead of turning on all the listed optimizations manually. For -O1 with the automotive_bitcount program, I measured a speedup of roughly 100% when compiling with -O1 instead of manually applying all the listed flags. Those "hidden" optimizations seem in fact to be the main part of the optimization work GCC does for -O1. When applying the flags manually, I only get a speedup of about 10% compared to no optimizations.
The same can be observed when applying all enabled flags from `gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers`.

In the GCC manual I found this section which would explain this behavior:

> Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag. Only optimizations that have a flag are listed in this section.
> Most optimizations are completely disabled at -O0 or if an -O level is not set on the command line, even if individual optimization flags are specified.

Since I couldn't find any further documentation on those optimizations, I wonder if there is a way of controlling them and what the optimizations are in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some optimizations are directly gated by `-O` flags e.g. [complete unroller](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/5c69acb32329d49e58c26fa41ae74229a52b9106/gcc/tree-ssa-loop-ivcanon.cc#L1647):

```
{
public:
  pass_complete_unrolli (gcc::context *ctxt)
    : gimple_opt_pass (pass_data_complete_unrolli, ctxt)
  {}

  /* opt_pass methods: */
  virtual bool gate (function *) { return optimize >= 2; }
  virtual unsigned int execute (function *);

}; // class pass_complete_unrolli
```

and for others `-O` influences their internal algorithms e.g. in [optimization of expressions](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/5c69acb32329d49e58c26fa41ae74229a52b9106/gcc/expr.cc#L486):

```
         /* If FROM is a SUBREG, put it into a register.  Do this
            so that we always generate the same set of insns for
            better cse'ing; if an intermediate assignment occurred,
            we won't be doing the operation directly on the SUBREG.  */
         if (optimize > 0 && GET_CODE (from) == SUBREG)
           from = force_reg (from_mode, from);
```

There is no way to work around this, you have to use `-O`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing me to the relevant sections in the source code! It's quite unfortunate that GCC doesn't provide more configuration here. Do you possibly also have a list over all the optimizations that are being applied in such a manner?

Comment: @tierriminator not really, usage of `-O` is scattered all over the codebase. I just grepped the sources for `\<optimize\>\|\<x_optimize\>`. Note that such list will need to be specific for each GCC release.

Comment: Indeed. However they already have release specific manuals…